# Windows sometimes render as multi-coloured static

Tags: nvidia, graphics, nvidia-geforce, visual-artifacts

Sometimes, when I restore a minimised window it will be entirely rendered as multi-colored static, until I minimise and restore the window again.

This seems to happen most reliably with [my VPN app](https://www.ivpn.net/apps-linux/), but I've also seen it happen with everything from Firefox to VLC and GIMP. When it happens with Anki it sometimes only happens partially, which I don't think I've seen for any other program. Here is a screenshot of the pattern:

[image: Screenshot of Anki with static patch]

As it's easy enough to clear up the static this doesn't impact me particularly, but does it suggest that my GPU may be failing? I'm using a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 460 which has been trucking along for about a decade now, but other than this I haven't seen any graphical issues.

I am using the ‘NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-390’ and this has occurred across at least Ubuntu 21.10 and 20.04, possibly earlier.

**Edit 2022-02-22**

Additional Drivers window:

[image: Additional Drivers dialog]

`dpkg -l *nvidia*`:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                          Version            Architecture Description
+++-=============================-==================-============-=========================================================
un  libgldispatch0-nvidia         <none>             <none>       (no description available)
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-390:amd64      390.144-0ubuntu2   amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
un  libnvidia-cfg1-any            <none>             <none>       (no description available)
un  libnvidia-common              <none>             <none>       (no description available)
ii  libnvidia-common-390          390.144-0ubuntu2   all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
un  libnvidia-compute             <none>             <none>       (no description available)
ii  libnvidia-compute-390:amd64   390.144-0ubuntu2   amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-390:i386    390.144-0ubuntu2   i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
un  libnvidia-decode              <none>             <none>       (no description available)
ii  libnvidia-decode-390:amd64    390.144-0ubuntu2   amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-390:i386     390.144-0ubuntu2   i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
un  libnvidia-encode              <none>             <none>       (no description available)
ii  libnvidia-encode-390:amd64    390.144-0ubuntu2   amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-390:i386     390.144-0ubuntu2   i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
un  libnvidia-fbc1                <none>             <none>       (no description available)
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-390:amd64      390.144-0ubuntu2   amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-390:i386       390.144-0ubuntu2   i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
un  libnvidia-gl                  <none>             <none>       (no description available)
ii  libnvidia-gl-390:amd64        390.144-0ubuntu2   amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-390:i386         390.144-0ubuntu2   i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
un  libnvidia-gl-460              <none>             <none>       (no description available)
un  libnvidia-gl-465              <none>             <none>       (no description available)
un  libnvidia-ifr1                <none>             <none>       (no description available)
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-390:amd64      390.144-0ubuntu2   amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386       390.144-0ubuntu2   i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
un  libnvidia-ml1                 <none>             <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-384                    <none>             <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-390                    <none>             <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-common                 <none>             <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-compute-utils          <none>             <none>       (no description available)
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-390      390.144-0ubuntu2   amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-dkms-390               390.144-0ubuntu2   amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
un  nvidia-dkms-kernel            <none>             <none>       (no description available)
ii  nvidia-driver-390             390.144-0ubuntu2   amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
un  nvidia-driver-binary          <none>             <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-kernel-common          <none>             <none>       (no description available)
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-390      390.144-0ubuntu2   amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
un  nvidia-kernel-source          <none>             <none>       (no description available)
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-390      390.144-0ubuntu2   amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
un  nvidia-libopencl1-dev         <none>             <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-opencl-icd             <none>             <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-persistenced           <none>             <none>       (no description available)
ii  nvidia-prime                  0.8.17.1           all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings               470.57.01-0ubuntu3 amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
un  nvidia-settings-binary        <none>             <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-smi                    <none>             <none>       (no description available)
un  nvidia-utils                  <none>             <none>       (no description available)
ii  nvidia-utils-390              390.144-0ubuntu2   amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390 390.144-0ubuntu2   amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

`dkms status`:

```
nvidia, 390.144, 5.13.0-28-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 390.144, 5.13.0-30-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.13.0-28-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 6.1.26, 5.13.0-30-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: What exact version is your Nvidia driver? 390.what? I see 390.1470 at their web site. Is the driver set to performance mode, or on-demand mode? Edit your question and show me a screenshot of the **Additional Drivers** window.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `dpkg -l *nvidia*` and `dkms status`.

Comment: @heynnema Additional information provided

Comment: Thanks for the data. It all looks fine. In the `Nvidia X Server Settings` PRIME Profiles tab, you can try changing it from "Performance" setting, to "On-Demand", or "Intel" and see if that helps. If it doesn't help, you may have to go to **Additional Drivers** and select the nouveau driver instead of the Nvidia driver.